# How can I wait for all processes to complete then do something?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a main method that spawns multiple processes (training k-folds in a cross validation) since I want to train all folds at the same time.

like this

```
def main(model=None, input_dir=None, output_dir=None, n_iter=100, dropout=0.5, batchsize=32.0):

        inputpath = os.path.abspath(input_dir)
        outputpath = os.path.abspath(output_dir)

        path = Path(inputpath)
        onlyfiles = [e for e in path.iterdir() if e.is_file()]

        for i in onlyfiles:
                if i.name.startswith("TRAIN_"):
                        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(model, i, outputpath, n_iter, dropout, batchsize))
                        p.start()
```

Then at the end what I want to do is run a function that evaluates the results.  But I think the main function exits once all the processes have been started.

I can only do the evaluation once all processes have completed and all models have been created.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to collect them all and call `join()` on all of them:

```
def main(model=None, input_dir=None, output_dir=None, n_iter=100, dropout=0.5, batchsize=32.0):
    # stuff elided ...
    all_processes = []
    for i in onlyfiles:
        if i.name.startswith("TRAIN_"):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(model, i, outputpath, n_iter, dropout, batchsize))
            p.start()
            all_processes.append(p)
    for p in all_processes:
        p.join()
    # Now do something else
```

Comment: does this cause each process to wait until the one before it finishes?

Comment: No, the loop is forced to wait inside each `join()` until *that* process has finished. If the first `p` happens to be the last to finish, the the loop waits that long inside the `join()` and the other `join()`s will become a 'nop'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [pool.starmap_async()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap_async)  method with a callback:

```
import multiprocessing

from multiprocessing import Pool

def callback(results):
    print(f'Processing: {results}')


def main(model=None, input_dir=None, output_dir=None, n_iter=100, dropout=0.5, batchsize=32.0):
    # stuff elided ...
    cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    args = ((model, i, outputpath, n_iter, dropout, batchsize) for i in onlyfiles)
    with Pool(processes=cpus) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap_async(worker, args, callback=callback)
        print(f'Done, results: {results.get()}')
```

or simply:

```
results = pool.starmap(worker, args)
print(f'Processing: {results}')
```

Comment: just to verify, this means it processes 'cpu' number of processes at a time right?  When I ran in jupyter-notebook I noticed that the call back doesn't print the string until all have completed, is that right?  Is there a way to get it to print output at each batch?

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. I thought you want to process/evaluate **all** results at the end?! If you're talking about getting status for tasks that are submitted to the pool you can add some logging to your `worker` function.

Comment: thanks, I found I didn't need the callback, so just removed it, and then I used sys.stdout.flush() to get the inner processes to print the status output to console